# How can this be done in the shortest way?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have saved the `class` holding the position of the `i` element in the `a` that is clicked by the user. When the `a` tag is clicked, I want to get the value of its `attr` and add it as a class to the `i` element tag. I have tried doing it as illustrated below but I feel like this to much code. How can this be done in the shortest wat possible?

```
    <i id="pps_ToggledIcon" class="pisp_p pISImage"></i>

    <li class="privListItem checkedList selectedList li_public">
        <a href="/p" class="psLink" title="pisp_p">
            <span class="privLabel">PP</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="privListItem checkedList selectedList li_public">
        <a href="/f" class="psLink" title="pisp_f">
            <span class="privLabel">F</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="privListItem checkedList selectedList li_public">
        <a href="/o" class="psLink" title="pisp_o">
            <span class="privLabel">O</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Here is the JS

```
    $(".xyp li a").on("click", function(e) {
       var pIcnSltd = $(this).attr("title"); 
       var pTIcn = $("#pps_ToggledIcon");
       if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_f") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_o")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_f");
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_o");
            pTIcn.addClass("pisp_p");
        }
        else if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_p") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_o")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_p");
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_o");
            pTIcn.addClass("pisp_f");
        }
        else if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_p") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_f")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_p");
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_f");
            pTIcn.addClass("pisp_f");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you seen http://codereview.stackexchange.com? It's good for these types of questions.. and I like to imagine an intelligent man with glasses sitting down to review my code over a cup of camomille tea.

Comment: It looks like you should be using a HTML5 `data-` attribute instead of `title`, and possibly also `.data()` instead of adding classes. That would knock it down to a single line.

Comment: Shouldn't the last `pTIcn.addClass("pisp_f");` be `pTIcn.addClass("pisp_o");`?

Comment: Also, `pIcnSltd` is assigned value but never used.

Answer (score 1):

How about just removing all classes, and then add back the `pISImage` class together with the clicked anchors title as a class:

```
$(".xyp li a").on("click", function() {
    $("#pps_ToggledIcon").removeClass().addClass('pISImage '+this.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports method chaining:

```
$(".xyp li a").on("click", function(e) {
       var pIcnSltd = $(this).attr("title"); 
       var pTIcn = $("#pps_ToggledIcon");
       if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_f") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_o")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_f").removeClass("pisp_o").addClass("pisp_p");
        }
        else if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_p") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_o")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_p").removeClass("pisp_o").addClass("pisp_f");
        }
        else if (pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_p") || pTIcn.hasClass("pisp_f")) {
            pTIcn.removeClass("pisp_p").removeClass("pisp_f").addClass("pisp_f");
        }
    });
```

But do keep in mind, shortest is not always `===` best. Also, your logic looks quite convoluted to me, I didn't even bother trying to decipher what you're trying to do.

If you want to simplify this code, you should really start by reconsidering your logic.

Comment: Simplest, however, is usually best. And this isn't simple by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ones noted and add one back

```
$(".xyp li a").on("click", function() {
    $("#pps_ToggledIcon").removeClass('pisp_f pisp_p pisp_o').addClass(this.title);
});
```

NOTE: IF you are OK removing all the classes, including the "other" pISImage one, use the solution by adeneo - hard to tell if that remove/add would introduce some unwanted effect or break other code (events management based on that class, visual manifestations etc)